# How to get rid of PermGen space?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, glassfish

I am fed up with the following annoying error, how can I get it solved ? would it solve the problem if I use Tomcat rather than GlassFish? I am running locally, would it be the same if I run the same application on the server?

```
SEVERE: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

SEVERE: Exception in module org.glassfish.main.core.kernel [228] : 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
SEVERE: Exception in module org.glassfish.main.core.kernel [228] : 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
SEVERE: Exception in thread "RMI RenewClean-[10.0.0.12:8686]"
```

Comment: We need more details, especially the JVM arguments.

Comment: I am newbie to Glassfish where can I find those arguments?

Comment: If you redeploy your app without restart your server this error will occur in some moment, because the container maintains the old copy of your application. It's a known issue: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/OutOfMemory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime you are redeploying the application need to restart the server to clean up its memory, as I have a similar issue with Tomcat.

Changing memory size just delay the problem but would not prevent it.

In addition, need to find memory leaks of your application using plugins of your IDE such as [Profiler](https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/nb-profiler-uncoveringleaks_pt1.html) for netbeans or other available software.

Moreover, as Shaunak said you can change the size of perm memory in /glassfish/domain/domain1/config/domain.xml file.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried increasing the memory for glassfish?

1) goto `"domain.xml`" in `/glassfish/domain/domain1/config`

look for `<jvm-options>-XX:MaxPermSize=`

increase its value e.g- `198m or 256m` or even more may be `1024m`.

2) Stop Glass fish then restart it .

Comment: No but I need to find the problem, otherwise need to change this memory size all the time.

Comment: Well if this memory is too low its a good idea to increase it 1024m anyway. You probably don't have any problem but it still runs out of memory doing regular things like compile, deploy etc. Increase the memory and then may me monitor Glassfish too see if it is continuously hogging up memory. Don't forget Java has a pretty efficient garbage collector :)

Comment: Also the error pointed out by @Juned is worth looking at once you increase your memory and if it still runs out.

Comment: it is currently 192m, permSize=64m MaxPermSize=192m

Comment: okay, if you have good  memory on your system try to increase it to 512m or 1024m

Comment: no not necessarily. Sometimes deploying does take a lot of memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running into this error, while trying to deploy your application for the first time, then increasing the permgen space through domain.xml config may help.

But be carefult, that you may be hitting a glassfish defect causing permgen error on on iterative deployments.

https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-587

Comment: After using the application for some few times, when I try to rerun it, it runs into this error

Comment: @TimNorman You may have to upgrade to the version containing this fix or as you mentioned in your question, if you want ,then move to tomcat.